# Why would my jquery/javascript be buggy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why would my jquery/javascript be buggy?
(using foundation 4.3.2 with Jquery 1.10.2)

Firefox always gives a message to stop the script: 
"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding..."

Here is the function that gives the problems

```
  function preparePlz() {
        $('#plzform').on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var plzVal = $('#plz').val();
            var regex = new RegExp("^([0-9]{5})$");
            if (!regex.test(plzVal)) {
                $('.errormessage').addClass("error");
                if ($('.errormessage').hasClass("hide")) {
                    $('.errormessage').removeClass("hide");
                }
                $("#plz ").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(regex.test(plzVal)) {
                $('.errormessage').addClass("hide");
                $('.errormessage').removeClass("error");
                $('#plz').removeClass("error");
                $('#message').removeClass("hide");
                var plzZone = plzVal.substring(0, 2);
                $('#plzModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
                    url: 'http://vaeplan.com/kontact/zone',
                    data: {showtemplate: false, r: plzZone}
                });
            }
        });
        preparePlz();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        preparePlz();
    });
```

Comment: You are creating an infinite loop by calling `preparePlz();` in his own function... So your browser will start using all the memory it can and eventually throw an error. Also try to give a clearer title stating your problem if your are going to post another time on stackoverflow.

Comment: You have an infinite loop but then come the question: what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last thing function `preparePlz` does is run itself:

```
preparePlz();
```

When the page loads `preparePlz` is run once, then goes into an infinite loop. 
Change

```
    });
    preparePlz();
}
```

to

```
    });

}
```

Comment: ok, an infinite loop was the problem, i moved the line up so it is called in the on click event.

Answer (score 11):

You have infinite recursion. Think about it, what happens on document ready? `preparePlz` is called. What happens inside `preparePlz`? `preparePlz` is called. What happens inside `preparePlz`? `preparePlz` is called.